# Ruby on Rails 4 AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in UsersController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller

Obviously I'm quite new to RoR and having a problem when adding a feature to force re-activation when a user changes her email in M.Hartl's great tutorial

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController    
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    save_email
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      check_email_change
      redirect_to @user and return
    else
      render 'edit'
    end   
  end

  # ...

  private
    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def save_email
      @old_email = @user.email
    end

    def check_email_change
      if @user.email.downcase != @old_email.downcase
        @user.activated = false
        @user.save
        flash[:warning] = "You've changed your email address."
        request_activation
        redirect_to logout_url and return
      end  
    end

    def request_activation
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
    end
  end
end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
  private
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end   
end
```

```
module SessionsHelper
  # ...

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem is that in `update` you call `check_email_change`, which calls `redirect_to`, and then `update` calls `redirect_to` again.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, So "and return" branches me out of the method but the responses keep building up due to multiple redirects ?

Comment: Right. `and return` branches you out of the `check_email_change` method and back to `update`, where you hit a second `redirect_to`.